# How does $e^\left(2i\pi\right) = 1$ result in $e^\left(i\pi\right) +1 = 0$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I can't see how  $$e^\left(2i\pi\right) = 1$$ 
will result in:
$$e^\left(i\pi\right) +1 = 0$$ 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't. However, $e^{i\pi}=-1$ *does* imply both $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ and $e^{2i\pi}=1$.

The more general result is that (multiplying by) $e^{i\theta}$ represents a counterclockwise rotation of the complex plane by an angle of $\theta$ about the origin. If $\theta=\pi$, then you rotate $180^\circ$, which is the same as multiplying by $-1$.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, I was aware of the geometric idea. i thought there is some kind of neat algebraic trick. which i understand from your response that doesn't exist.

Comment: @math_student If you perform a certain rotation of the plane twice, and the end result is no net change, then we can't tell whether the operation we did was $180^\circ$ rotation or $0^\circ$. That's why we can't get from $e^{2i\pi}=1$ to $e^{i\pi}=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Algebra wll not do what you want.  But algebra does this much:

Note if $z = e^{i\pi}$, then $z^2 = e^{2\pi i}$.  Now if $e^{2\pi i}= 1$, that is, $z^2 = 1$, we get $z^2-1 = 0$ or $(z-1)(z+1) = 0$ so that either $z=1$ or $z=-1$.

The complex number $1$ has two square roots.

Comment: @Arthur's comment nailed it i guess.